# How to compile a template from a string?

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

How to compile a template from a string?   
 
Example:

s = "Hello  {{#each users}} {{FirstName}},  {{/each}}"

You need to get:

s = "Hello User 1, User 2, User 3,

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish?

Comment: There is a record in MongoDB page template with the variables of the form {{variable}} and cycles such as {{# each}} {{/ each}}. You want to display this pattern of MongoDB and compile.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you want to do. Maybe this:

Put this in an .html-file:

```
<template name="someTemplate">

   Hello {{#each users}} {{FirstName}}, {{/each}}

</template>
```

Put this in a .js-file:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

   Template.someTemplate.helpers({
      users: function() {
         // "Users" is a Meteor Collection
         return Users.find({});
      }
   });

}
```

Comment: Found something similar, but this template to specify the events and variables ..

Comment: `var tmpl = Meteor._def_template("templateName", function () { 
    return "some html string"; 
});`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you want to accomplish.